Does the Gunner feat let you ignore the Reload property?
The Gunner feat says: "You ignore the loading property of firearms."
Does this also apply to weapons with the Reload property (such as a revolver)?

No
Reload and loading are different properties. Gunner feat affects only one of them, as its description says. If it affected another property, it would say so. There are no secret rules.
Keep in mind their descriptions are quite different as well:

Loading. Because of the time required to load this weapon, you can fire only one piece of ammunition from it when you use an action, bonus action, or reaction to fire it, regardless of the number of attacks you can normally make.


Reload. A limited number of shots can be made with a weapon that has the reload property. A character must then reload it using an action or a bonus action (the character’s choice).

Reload requires to explicitly reload the weapon as an action, while loading limits the fire rate. I'd say reload is less restrictive, since you can reload a weapon using your bonus action.
